# PFSignUpView + PFLoginView persisting user across app launches

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm having trouble persisting users across app launches using the Parse iOS SDK.  I know when you login/signup using "saveInBackgroundWithBlock", the SDK automatically caches the PFUser, but now when I'm using PFLoginView + PFSignUpView, the user doesn't persist.

I know this because when the code:

```
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
            self.presentNextView()
        }
```

is run on viewDidLoad of the sign up view, the current user is set to nil after relaunching the app.  Could someone please shed some light???

Comment: Check if you have PFUser.enableAutomaticUser() in your AppDelegate. If you have, comment it out and try again

Comment: I don't have PFUser.enableAutomaticUser() in my AppDelegate